# export/import all the information of a table

Tags: db2, database

For a mandatory assignment of a DB2 class I'm asked to write o procedure to export "export information about all xxx, delete all xxx and import the information again." where xxx is my table.
This procedure has to be as efficiently as possible.

I'm quite stuck here, quite naively I see two options
1) write a select * from xxx; drop ...; insert; using python or something
2) using some export/import utility of db2

But I can be totally wrong, suggestions?

what I've noticed is that there are not integrity constraints.

Comment: few more information, I can run the command on the server (I guess is fine) and the table I have to export (just a single table) has 10^6 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via "export/load/[set integrity](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000998.html)". I think it  is the best way if you execute that in the server.

If you use python, you will have to use a odbc driver or similar to get the data, processes, etc.

If you use python just to execute the commands, it is ok, finally, it is just a call to the database.

If you execute the process in other machine, the net use is increased, and the performance is lower.

Using import, it is just like an "insert" per row in the file which uses a lot of transaction log. Instead, the load command, puts the data diretly in the tablespace and then check the referential integrity (faster process)

Finally, if you want to extract the information very fast, you can buy the [IBM InfoSphere® Optim™ High Performance Unload for DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/common/ssi/ecm/en/imb14122usen/IMB14122USEN.PDF)

Comment: I commented my question with few more information, as I see the best way seems to run a system command on python..something like system(db2 export ....) right?

Comment: ok right now I'm using the command `db2 export to myfile2.del of del  "select * from xxx"` what about the import? is not really clear how to use it. and why should I use the integrity command?

Comment: Yes, you can use python as a script file. You will be calling db2 commands, and the whole process will be inside the database.

Comment: When you use "import", db2 will process the file as an "insert into" sentence for each row, writing that in the transaction logs, and commiting at the end. Instead, there is a tool to insert faster in DB2 that do not use transaction logs, which is the load command. The only thing, is that after the load, you have to run set integrity to validate the data. Do in Google: db2 load vs import and you will see. For example: http://blogs.oracle.com/enelcentro/entry/load_vs_import_in_db2

Comment: I get this `SQL3306N  An SQL error "-964" occurred while inserting a row into the table.
SQL0964C  The transaction log for the database is full.  SQLSTATE=57011` error using the import. I need to try the import and load both to document my experiments

Comment: You just have to modify the logging preferences. LOGFILSIZ * (LOGPRIMARY + LOGSECOND) http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/r0006082.html
You are producing a lot of activity in the database and the logs are not enough to write that.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar task before. 
The solution is simple and sweet:
A simple export to csv; and once the data has been exported, the main thing is to TRUNCATE the table with your logs being disabled and then load the data back into the table.

```
EXPORT TO <FileName>.CSV OF DEL SELECT * FROM <TableName>;
ALTER TABLE <TableName> ACTIVATE NOT LOGGED INITIALLY WITH EMPTY TABLE;
LOAD FROM "./<FileName>.CSV" OF DEL INSERT INTO <TableName>;
```